# iOS button backgroundImage vs image

Tags: ios

for a button I see 2 fields: background image and image. Is the only difference that a background image allows for text on top of it?

Answer (score 7):

These images serve different purposes.

The `backgroundImage` is the graphical representation of the button. This image typically represents the different possible states of the button (normal, selected, highlighted) and is usually stretchable (horizontally and/or vertically) to be usable with varied button sizes.

The `image` is content that sits within the button and is the graphical analogy to the `text` property.

A common usage pattern would be to use the same `backgroundImage` for multiple buttons in your app for a consistent theme but to use different `images` depending on the contextual meaning of each button.

Also, `backgroundImage` is not used for layout calculations. For example, `[myButton sizeToFit]` will take into account the `image` but not the `backgroundImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the only difference I know

Comment: Correct, the only difference *you know.*